# GDB - Call second program

Tags: io-redirection, gdb

I have a program which I want to debug `gdb`. And I want to call a second program to redirect the output to the first program. How this is done in `gdb`.

I tried it like that:

```
run -2 < $(python seconde.py)
```

But that does not work :(

Comment: Outside of gdb, how would you run the program? `prog -2 < $(python seconde.py)` or `prog -2 <(python seconde.py)`?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is: `run $(python seconde.py)`

Comment: Please [edit](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/252237/edit) your question to respond to the clarifying question Mark Plotnick asked yesterday.  Please edit either the question or [the answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/252420/edit) to explain why you thought `-2` was part of the answer, and how the actual answer you have posted can work without it.